# Handling memory allocation by myself in xcode (c++)

Tags: c++, xcode, memory, automatic-ref-counting, allocation

I have turned of Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) in my Xcode 4.3.2, and thought I was in good hands. Then I wrote this little program:

```
int main()
{
    int *a = new int(3);
    delete a;
    printf("%i",*a);
    return 0;
}
```

Which is printing 3, but it should print garbage. It looks like the compiler takes care of all my memory allocations, which I don't want it to do. What do I have to do to remove that?

Comment: What you are printing is undefined behavior, but it happens to be 3 because most likely the memory has not been modified between lines 2 and 3

Comment: It also happends to be whatever I choose it to be.. In another compiler, (p.e codepad), it's garbage. as it should be..

Comment: Yes it is printing garbage. The garbage just randomly happens to be 3. The trouble with humans is most don't understand true randomness.http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: Is this happening in both debug and release builds?

Comment: @dirkgently Yes, it happends in both debug and release build.

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't mean you're guaranteed to get garbage. Undefined means anything can happen, and printing out '3' is perfectly conformant behavior. Other things this program could legally do: start playing music at random from your library, cause your monitor to burst into flame, email all of your friends hate mail appearing to come from you.

Comment: Also, ARC doesn't currently manage memory for C++, just Objective-C's reference counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give your program an address on the heap with new. It happens to be an integer with the value 3 at that address.
When you free that heap area with delete, it is not immediately set to some garbage value, it still contains 3. 
Your print statement goes to the address at a and tries to print the integer that is there, it finds 3 and prints it.

You could try adding compiler warnings if this is possible in xcode, I know gcc and other command line compilers offer this feature, to avoid these confusing undefined behaviors from occurring with out the program yelling at you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for it. On my other machines (not mac, ergo not Xcode), it always displays garbage, makes it confusing...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996108/where-to-add-wall-and-wextra-in-xcode-3-1-4

These flags should help.

Comment: You can also unmap that memory if you use `mmap` and `munmap`.. then OS will send a SIGSEGV signal.

Comment: @Vlad isn't mmapping an entirely different concept not related to the question at hand?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: No it is not, there are a lot of cases where using malloc/free is not enough, and so people use mmap, splice and other things. It's all memory management. Munmap, however, unmaps virtual memory (really frees it), and that really "frees".